How to use conditional formatting to highlight occurrences across two columns
I am trying to count the number of products per shipment, each occurrence of the same vessel name on the same date means a new product. So, in the example below, on the 10/06, Vessel A delivered three products, and Vessel B and C delivered one product each. How do I count these instances where "shipment_date=duplicate & vessel_name=duplicate"



Shipment date
Vessel name




10/06
A


10/06
A


10/06
A


10/06
B


10/06
C



Unfortunately I can't share the file itself, so hopefully this is a good enough explanation.
Thanks
Tried highlighting duplicate values in vessel name column. Also tried creating a countifs rule.

Have you tried Pivot Table? The title and the content of your question is not covers the same?

To highlight duplicates try this formula: =IF(COUNTIFS($B$2:$B$6,B2;$A$2:$A$6,A2)>1,1,0)

I will look into pivot tables now. Sorry I realize now that title doesn't really make any sense, I thought at first it would be easiest to use conditional formatting. I have very little experience with excel, and 0 with pivot tables but hopefully they can help
